# Flutter Background Locator 2: How to Start Location Service in the Background in android 13 In release mode?

Tags: android, flutter, location, background-service

I'm using the Flutter Background Locator 2 package in my Flutter app to track the user's location in the background. However, I'm facing an  **[image: Screenshot of the Error Message]Missing type parameter** issue when trying to start the location service when the app is in the background, specifically on Android 13.

Unable to start service yukams.app.background_locator_2.IsolateHolderService@d327f59 with Intent { act=START cmp=com.smarthcm.mobile/yukams.app.background_locator_2.IsolateHolderService (has extras) }: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter

## What I've Tried

I have attempted the following steps to address the issue:

1. Reviewed the documentation for Flutter Background Locator 2 to ensure that I'm using it correctly.
2. Verified that location permissions are properly set in my app's AndroidManifest.xml file.
3. Confirmed that the necessary dependencies and configurations for Flutter Background Locator 2 are correctly installed in my Flutter project.
4. Checked for any updates or bug reports related to Flutter Background Locator 2 that might address the issue on Android 13.
5. Experimented with different settings and configurations in the Flutter Background Locator 2 package to see if the issue could be resolved.

### Expected Behavior

When starting the location service with an intent on Android 13 using Flutter Background Locator 2, I expect the following behavior:

1. The location service should start successfully in the background even when the app is not in the foreground.
2. The app should be able to receive location updates and handle them accordingly.
3. There should be no crashes or errors related to starting the location service with an intent on Android 13.

I'm looking for assistance in achieving this expected behavior or any insights into why it might not be working as expected on Android 13.